# Expected "}" at end of input when including d3dx11.h

Tags: c++, directx

I know what the error "Expected '}' before end of input" means, the issue I'm having is that the error appears to be in one of the files included with d3dx11.h, as when I don't include this file and comment out the DirectX calls in my code I don't get the error.

When I search for this error, I get results, but all results I find are errors in the users code (additional or missing braces), the error for me seems to be occurring inside the included files so after 6 hours I haven't found any help.

I'm relatively new to C++, and at this time I'm just trying to experiment and understand how things work, so I don't really care too much about naming conventions or what I may be putting in the header files that should go into the corresponding cpp file according to standard practice. My code may not be the cleanest and may have some inefficiencies, feel free to additionally point out places I could improve upon, but for this question I'm mostly asking what's causing the error:

```
C:/Program Files/CodeLite/.../main.cpp:33:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
```

As I said earlier, this error doesn't occur until I include DirectX.

**main.cpp**

```
#ifndef INCL_WINDOWS_H
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#define INCL_WINDOWS_H
#endif

#include <iostream>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#    pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
#endif

#define OS_WINDOWS
#include "WindowUtils.h"
#include "RenderUtils_Creation.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Window window("Test Window",100,100,900,900);

    while(window.getAlive())
    {
        window.process();
    }

    return window.getExitCode();
} // <-- Line 33, error occurs here, only when DX is included in RenderUtils_Creation.h
```

**WindowUtils.h**

```
#ifndef INCL_WINDOW_UTILS
#define INCL_WINDOW_UTILS
enum DisplayMode // Currently Unused (TBI)
{
    WINDOWED,
    FULLSCREEN,
    WINDOWED_NOBORDER
};

// DEFINE TEMPLATE FOR IMPLEMENTATION FEATURES

class ImplementationFeatures;

// DEFINE PLATFORM SPECIFIC IMPLEMENTATION OF IMPLEMENTATION FEATURES

#ifdef OS_WINDOWS

class ImplementationFeatures
{
public:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch(msg)
        {
            case WM_CLOSE:
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    HINSTANCE procInst;
    WNDCLASSEX wndStruct;
    HWND windowHandle;
    MSG msg;
};
#endif

// DEFINE TEMPLATE FOR WINDOW

class Window
{
public:
    ImplementationFeatures features;
    Window(char*, int, int, int, int);
    bool getAlive();
    void setDisplayMode(DisplayMode);
    void process();
    void update();
    int getExitCode();
};

// DEFINE PLATFORM-SPECIFIC IMPLEMENTATIONS OF WINDOW

#ifdef OS_WINDOWS

Window::Window(char* title, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height)
{
    ImplementationFeatures feature;

    LPCTSTR strTitle = title;

    feature.procInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    feature.wndStruct.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    feature.wndStruct.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    feature.wndStruct.lpfnWndProc = feature.WinProc;
    feature.wndStruct.cbClsExtra = 0;
    feature.wndStruct.cbWndExtra = 0;
    feature.wndStruct.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    feature.wndStruct.hIcon = NULL;
    feature.wndStruct.hCursor = NULL;
    feature.wndStruct.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_BTNFACE);
    feature.wndStruct.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    feature.wndStruct.lpszClassName = "WindowClassName";
    feature.wndStruct.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&(feature.wndStruct));

    feature.windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, "WindowClassName", strTitle, WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE, xPos, yPos, width, height, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ShowWindow(feature.windowHandle, 1);
    UpdateWindow(feature.windowHandle);

    features = feature;
}
bool Window::getAlive()
{
    return GetMessage(&features.msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0;
}
void Window::process()
{
    TranslateMessage(&(features.msg));
    DispatchMessage(&(features.msg));
}
void Window::update()
{
    UpdateWindow(features.windowHandle);
}
void Window::setDisplayMode(DisplayMode mode)
{
    switch(mode)
    {
        case WINDOWED:
            ShowWindow(features.windowHandle,1);
            break;
        case WINDOWED_NOBORDER:
            ShowWindow(features.windowHandle,1);
            break;
        case FULLSCREEN:
            ShowWindow(features.windowHandle,1);
            break;
    }
}
int Window::getExitCode()
{
    return features.msg.wParam;
}

#endif // End OS_WINDOWS
#endif // End INCL_WINDOW_UTILS
```

**RenderUtils_Creation.h**

```
#ifndef INCL_RENDER_UTILS_CRTN
#define INCL_RENDER_UTILS_CRTN

//This won't be included on the main.cpp because of the header guard
//Bug is included in case of use on other files
#include "WindowUtils.h"

#ifdef OS_WINDOWS

// Use Direct3D

//#define SKIP_DIRX // To quickly go back and forth testing if error is DX related
// When commented out d3d11.h and d3dx11.h are included with their libs
// When not commented none are included
// The error only occurs when this is commented.

#ifndef SKIP_DIRX

// Import Headers
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>

// include the Direct3D Library files
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")

#endif


#endif // End of OS_WINDOWS


#endif // End of INCL_RENDER_UTILS_CRTN
```

main.cpp is the only .cpp file and has no header. I'm attempting to create a cross-platform library for interfacing with different OS and graphics APIs. By defining OS_WINDOWS DirectX will be the API compiled against, for Mac I would then add code to interface to Metal, etc. I'm use to this abstraction, I've done similar with Java in the past, but this error is confusing me.

**Edit - Additional info that may be important:**

- Compiler: MinGW GCC Compiler (TDM-GCC-32)
- IDE: CodeLite

  - Version: 8.2.0
  - Does library search paths include DirectX SDK 'Lib' folder: Yes
  - Does include search paths include DirectX SDK 'includes' folder: Yes
- Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)

  - Standard installation

From further research it would appear that at least part of my problem could be because of Microsoft developing their own standards for their C++ compiler. The VisualC++ compiler adds in custom operators, intrinsic functions, macros and alternate versions of other standard functions that don't exist in other compilers because they are not C++ standards, they are custom Microsoft-specific additions. The DirectX header files apparently are reliant on the presence of these features and thus Microsoft essentially is forcing anyone who uses DirectX to use their compiler, at least for certain parts of their program.

Comment: Off topic: Rather than conditional compilation, consider building a common interface header, pretty much just `class Window` and put all of the platform specific implementation in a CPP file. Use a different CPP file for each platform and let the linker handle putting the right stuff together for each platform.

Comment: Yeah, the main issue is that I've only used C++ for around 2-3 months. I've tried using cpp files with the headers but I always get stupid errors that I can't understand why they exist referring to how one cpp file can't use certain features from another cpp file unless they are fully defined in the header file and other stuff that makes no sense and is leftover bloat from many years ago. I've always had far better luck with header-only apis, once it's compiled it hardly makes much difference anyways. I'll attempt to do so it this way gives me and issues, thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. I set up a VS2013 project with a main.cpp and the two headers (in separate directories, not that this is important). I copied + pasted your exact implementation, with the exception of commenting out some `LPCTSTR` stuff that wouldn't compile. I added an include directory to point to my dx11 files so I can simply write `#include <d3d11.h>` etc. I commented out the `#pragma comment` cause I couldn't find my libraries.

Comment: So: are you sure you haven't accidentally modified the dx11 files at all? Can you obtain new ones? Perhaps hard-code the include paths, or check your additional includes directories to make sure it is definitely including the right files.

Comment: I literally just installed te libraries today, haven't touched a single line in them. They're the standard installation of the Microsoft DirectX SDK, shouldn't have anything wrong with them, that's why I'm confused. But LPCSTR not compiling? that makes no sense if you've included windows.h as that's just a typedef.

Comment: I tried doing a bit more research, thinking maybe it's an incompatibility with the compiler I'm using. According to what I'm reading the DirectX headers rely upon features that Microsoft added to the VC++ compiler that simply do not exist in pretty much every other major compiler on the internet which honestly is simply stupid. I can't use VC++ because even the community versions, which are advertised as "free" cost monthly license payments to use an IDE that actually lacks on many common C++ features and adds their own features that aren't standard, making their program required.

Comment: The DirectX SDK itself is deprecated. All versions of D3DX are as well. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). The DirectX SDK (June 2010) officially supported only Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010. You can get it to work with VS 2012 and VS 2013 with caveats, and even more caveats with VS 2015. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition.aspx). The VS 2013 Community and VS 2015 Community editions already include Direct3D11 headers without using the legacy DXSDK.

Comment: If you are new to C++, then perhaps you are making a lot of assumptions about the quality of the Visual Studio 2015 Community edition tools. Try it out, learn C++, and then if you desire switch to GCC tools for your projects once you understand how the language works. Also, you don't actually *need* to use the deprecated D3DX11 library in order to use Direct3D 11. There are a number of [replacements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx), but I can't vouch for their compatibility with GCC.

Comment: Microsoft is notorius for not following standards. When I say new, I am talking relative to other langauges. I have 9 years of Java and several years with other languages. I know how to do research on an IDE. Visual studio Community is still a paid program, you get a free trial and are then required to pay money to continue. I have used Visual Studio in the past, and I don't mind Visual Studio, but I will not pay $20+ a month for an IDE that doesn't have any major advantage to other IDEs except for the standardized features that they use to force people to use their programs.

Comment: And by "forcing users to use their programs" I'm talking about the fact that DirectX header files rely on non-standard pre-processor token parsing, allowance of goto over initialization, custom intrinsic functions like __noop, tons of custom aliases and custom operators like __uuidof. These aren't existant in almost all other IDE's because they are not part of the C++ standard, they are things that MS came upp with themselves and implemented and used, forcing people to use their custom compiler to use their tools like DirectX. To me, that's simply stupid.

Comment: Also, how can DirectX be depricated when DX12 came out very recently. If you're going to say the tools provided by Microsoft themselves are deprecated, provide something that details their successor.

Comment: For clarification Chuck Walbourn, I am developing for my operating system, which in Windows 7, which a majority of Windows users still use and having updated to 8 or 10. I'm not about to update to an operating system that is still extremely buggy and messed up about 30% of the people who moved over to it's computers. I don't have the luxury of the SDK features being included in the Windows SDK because of such, to say it's deprecated means there's something that succeeds it, it may be deprecated for Windows 8+, but it's not for Windows 7 and below unless there's a different package available..

Comment: The DirectX SDK is deprecated, not the DirectX API as covered on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) link I provided. The D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 utility libraries are deprecated for a number of reasons, but for Direct3D 11 there are a number of alternatives.

Comment: The Windows 8.x SDK, the Windows 10 SDK, and VS 2015 Community all support development on and targeting Windows 7 SP1. VS 2015 Community supports developing Direct3D 11 Windows desktop applications for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8.0, Windows 8.1, and/or Windows 10.

Comment: I simply don't understand. The link you gave named the ONLY reason for the SDK being deprecated was that the API is included in Windows 8 and above. And the link you gave to the alternative for D3DX was a list of around 20 individual libraries that yo need to get them all to replace D3DX, which is a single library which makes integrating it much less of a pain. Next, for the last time, even the Community edition of Visual Studio costs money after a free trial for 1 month, I'm not going to pay Microsoft money for an IDE which is generally below-par with many other free ones out there today.

Comment: The part that's really making me mad is the fact that this is a scheme by Microsoft to make money. Microsoft's compiler is hardly even C++, it's their own version of C++, with additional features that are not on the standard and are practically useless, at the same time omitting other features of standard C++ that other compilers have. However Direct3D requires the presence of these features, and thus FORCE people to have to use their compiler. To me that's blatantly immoral, it's a scheme for MS to make more money from. I'm trying for cross-platform, I can't do that with the VC++ compiler.

Comment: The entire point of NOT using VC++ compiler was so I wouldn't have to change any base code to compile against different platforms, only implementation code. VC++ can only compile for windows, and to make code valid for that compiler requires code that can never compile on other compilers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97326/discussion-between-d3-jmultiply-and-chuck-walbourn).